# List of multiple types in Haskell

Tags: generics, haskell, types, functional-programming, polymorphism

Say I have a set of records, as in

```
data A = A { a:: String } deriving (Show)
data B = B { b:: String } deriving (Show)
```

Then some type class

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> IO ()

instance Foo A where
    foo c = ...
```

And I also want to do something like

```
bar = do
    push (A {a="x"})
    push (B {b="y"})
```

And have these things end up in a list l somewhere to be run at a later time, such that I can

```
map foo l
```

Should I write template haskell to generate a wrapper type and derive instances so the list can be of the wrapper type? Is there a more intelligent way to go about this? I'm honestly feeling pretty pinned down by the haskell type system, and know there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are ways to do this with existential quantification, but it's often overkill. A more Haskell-y approach would be to simply apply `foo` up front and keep a `[IO ()]` list of the resulting actions, which you can then `sequence` later to run them.

Comment: See also the [FAQ entry](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#I.27m_making_an_RPG._Should_I_define_a_type_for_each_kind_of_monster.2C_and_a_type_class_for_them.3F) on this, and the [article it links to](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).

Comment: So you can have `thingsToDo :: [IO()]` defined by `thingsToDo = [foo A, foo B]` or even `stuffToDo :: IO ()` with `stuffToDo = foo A >> foo B`

Answer (score 2):

An example using `Existential`, but I would really abstain from using it and would suggest what hammar told.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data A = A String deriving Show
data B = B String deriving Show

class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> IO ()

instance Foo A where
    foo c = putStrLn $ "FOOA " ++ show c

instance Foo B where
    foo c = putStrLn $ "FOOB " ++ show c

data Wrap = forall a . Foo a => Wrap a

instance Foo Wrap where
    foo (Wrap c) = foo c

bar :: [Wrap]
bar = [Wrap $ A "x", Wrap $ B "y"]

main = mapM_ foo bar
```